# How do I Restrict no of requests on Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I want to restrict no of requests per minute from single origin.I have researched on it and got that AWS WAF can do this but i don't know how that rule can be created for this  particular use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Elastic Load Balancer does not support rate based limiting. You can do this with AWS WAF but it has some limitations like 5 min time span, minimum 100 req per ip
See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-rate-based.html

Comment: hi thanks for answer.can we reduce this timespan because 5 min is very large for me?

Comment: No you can't reduce it